# Help in understanding a limit involving an integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

$$ I_n = \int^1_0\frac{x^n}{ax+b}dx $$
Where: $n \in N$ ; $a,b \in (0,\infty)$"

---

Find $\Xi$, where: $$\Xi=\lim_{n \to \infty}nI_n$$

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integration by parts gives:
$$ nI_n = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{n x^n}{ax+b}\,dx =\left. x^n \cdot\frac{x}{ax+b}\right|_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{b x^n}{(ax+b)^2}\,dx$$
hence:
$$ n I_n = \color{red}{\frac{1}{a+b}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) $$
since:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{bx^n}{(ax+b)^2}\,dx\leq \frac{1}{b}\int_{0}^{1} x^n\,dx = \frac{1}{b(n+1)}.$$

Comment: I had done step one; the last integral was what bugged me. Could you please explain how you got that inequality? And thank you.

Comment: @Kugelblitz: it is just a consequence of $(ax+b)^2 \geq b^2$. $a,b,x$ are non-negative.